# How can i get just the model from /proc/cpuinfo?

Tags: linux, grep

I need to get the model of processors.
Using:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model'
```

Returns:

`model        : 60 
model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
model        : 60
model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
model        : 60
model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz
model        : 60
model name    : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4460  CPU @ 3.20GHz`

And i need:

```
model        : 60
model        : 60
model        : 60
model        : 60
```

I don't want to grep after value i need to grep after model.
How can i get this?

Thanks,

Comment: You should also be able to get this from CPUID (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D1:_Processor_Info_and_Feature_Bits). Other Q&A on this site documented the details.

Answer (score 2):

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -E 'model[[:space:]]*:'
```

or

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -P 'model\s*:'
```

should do the trick -- the latter will only work on grep versions that support the -P flag for perl compatible regular expressions, such as GNU grep.